# How to add intellisense to a search line in java swing

Tags: java, xml, swing, awt, intellisense

This is my first time with **intellisense** so please go easy on me :)

I'm using Java swing for building a search engine for viewing `XML` files .

At the moment the XML file is uploaded and searched successfully , however I still

would like to add the `intellisense` element to the project .

It's very hard to be specific since the code is pretty big , then I'll do my best to be

as specific as I could .

Here is a visual picture of the XML search engine : 
[image]

Now , after the user uploaded the `XML` file (using the open button on the **left**)

he enters a query in the **current path:* box . Each part of the query is separated via `/` , hence what I want is to give to the user my options when he hits `/` , which they are :

```
String[] axesTypes = {"child::", "attribute::", "descendant::",
                                        "descendant-or-self::", "slef::", "parent::",
                                        "following-sibling::", "preceding-sibling::",
                                        "ancestor-or-self::", "ancestor::", "following::",
                                        "preceding::" ,"preceding::", "namespace::", "node()"};
```

I'd appreciate if someone can give an explanation regarding how to add that element to my project .

If you need me to post the code - please say so , and I would .

Regards

Comment: http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/java/swing/autosuggest.html check this and apply the logic

Comment: @bunta: This is a very impressive code , I compiled it as a separate program and it runs perfectly . However when I try to attach it with my code , the outcomes are not pretty . Can I post the problematic code here ? thanks again .