# How to combine two threads for the goal of auto-completion (intelliSense)

Tags: java, swing, autocomplete, awt, intellisense

Following my previous post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10911554/how-to-add-intellisense-to-a-search-line-in-java-swing) , kind mr. `@bunta` suggested to use the code from [here](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/java/swing/autosuggest.html)
and use it with my code in order to make the auto-completion to work .

The problem is that I'm already using a thread .

Here is the partial code (it's pretty big then I post only what matters) :

```
private javax.swing.JTextField boxOfCurrentPath;

// more code 

boxOfCurrentPath.setToolTipText("");
boxOfCurrentPath.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() 
{
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
        {
            boxOfCurrentPathActionPerformed(evt);
        }
   });
```

But when I try to add another thread , the auto-completion example from the above with my current code ,nothing happens . The code runs without auto-completion :

```
boxOfCurrentPath.setToolTipText("");

boxOfCurrentPath.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() 
{
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
    {
        boxOfCurrentPathActionPerformed(evt);
    }

     class AutoSuggest2 extends JPanel
    {
         private final JTextField tf;
         private final JComboBox combo = new JComboBox();
         private final Vector<String> v = new Vector<String>();


        public AutoSuggest2() 

        {
            super(new BorderLayout());
            combo.setEditable(true);
            tf = (JTextField) combo.getEditor().getEditorComponent();
            tf.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() 
            {
              public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) 
              {
                   EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() 
                {
                    String text = tf.getText();

                        if(text.length()==0) 

                        {
                        combo.hidePopup();
                        setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(v), "");
                        }

                        else
                        {
                            DefaultComboBoxModel m = getSuggestedModel(v, text);
                            if(m.getSize()==0 || hide_flag) 
                            {
                                combo.hidePopup();
                                hide_flag = false;
                            }

                            else
                            {
                                setModel(m, text);
                                combo.showPopup();
                            }

                        } // end else 

                } // end run 
                });

              } // end keyTyped   

              public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) 
              {
                  String text = tf.getText();
                  int code = e.getKeyCode();
                  if(code==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) 
                  {
                        if(!v.contains(text)) 
                        {
                            v.addElement(text);
                            Collections.sort(v);
                            setModel(getSuggestedModel(v, text), text);
                        }
                        hide_flag = true; 
                  } 

                  else 
                      if(code==KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE)
                      {
                          hide_flag = true; 
                      }
                      else 

                          if(code==KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) 
                          {
                              for(int i=0;i<v.size();i++) 
                              {
                                  String str = v.elementAt(i);
                                  if(str.startsWith(text)) 
                                  {
                                      combo.setSelectedIndex(-1);
                                      tf.setText(str);
                                      return;
                                  }
                              }
                          }
                }  // end keyPressed
          }); // end addKeyListener


        String[] axesTypes = 
            {"child::", "attribute::", "descendant::", "descendant-or-self::", 
             "slef::", "parent::", "following-sibling::", "preceding-sibling::",
             "ancestor-or-self::", "ancestor::", "following::", "preceding::" ,
             "preceding::", "namespace::", "node()"};


            for(int i=0;i<axesTypes.length;i++)
            {
                      v.addElement(axesTypes[i]);
            }
            setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(v), "");
            JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            p.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("AutoSuggestion Box"));
            p.add(combo, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            add(p);
            setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5,5,5,5));
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 150));

        } // end AutoSuggest


        private boolean hide_flag = false;

        private DefaultComboBoxModel getSuggestedModel(java.util.List<String> list, String text)
        {
                DefaultComboBoxModel m = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
                for(String s: list) 
                {
                    if(s.startsWith(text)) m.addElement(s);
                }
                return m;
        }


        private void setModel(DefaultComboBoxModel mdl, String str)
        {
         combo.setModel(mdl);
         combo.setSelectedIndex(-1);
         tf.setText(str);
        }



    } // end AutoSuggest2 extends 

});
```

I'm clearly doing something wrong, but can't seem to understand why .Any ideas? thanks !

Comment: You may wish to do some debugging first to try to isolate where your problems are coming from. Then you'll be able to post a more reasonable amount of relevant code.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: Believe me I have, the problem is not with the example code , but with my code . Debugging didn't help much , but I'll try again .

Comment: Well, if you get a decent answer soon, then don't bother, but my experience here suggests that we do much better at helping with problems that are well isolated, then with problems where you're not clear yet what the problem is. No one can compile nor run your code as posted, and no one will have time to go through your whole program, so unfortunately you and we are kind of stuck. By the way, you probably don't want to use a KeyListener, but rather a DocumentFilter.

Comment: What is all that 'another Thread' you are talking about ? I do not see it in the code you posted (which is basically a copy of that RoseIndia site which I try to avoid as much as possible).